# Does adding a foreign key to a table affect its insertion time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2014

Is the assumption that each foreign key added a to a table also adds a `CHECK` constraint that ensures that values inserted in the foreign key column is from the set of values from the table where that key is the primary key.

This would imply that a table with more foreign keys would take longer to insert a value into. Is this correct?

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

Comment: A `CHECK` constraint is a separate type of constraint, unrelated to a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint. The overhead of foreign key and other constraints is the price of data integrity. Nothing is free.

Comment: Thank you. I do understand they're different, but I didn't know I could drop the CHECK constraint and still have a foreign key. Can I?

Comment: You can have both check and foreign key constraints on the same column but if the functionality is redundant, you can simply drop the check constraint. Both will restrict the domain of possible values. A check constraint will perform better but requires code modifications to add/remove values whereas a foreign key constraint allows the values to be constrained dynamically based on the referenced table and allows one to store additional attributes in the referenced table that should be stored in a separate table per standard database model normalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Foreign key relationships are checked when data is inserted or modified in the table.

The foreign key needs to be to a primary key or unique key.  This guarantees that an index is available for the check.

In general, looking up the value in the index should be pretty fast.  Faster than the other things that are going on in an insert, such as finding a free page for the data and logging the data.

However, validating the foreign key is going to add some overhead.

Comment: Thank you. Just one more thing: is it usual/normal if almost every table of mine has about 5 foreign keys? 9 more minutes before I can mark your answer as the right one.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 . . . That seems like a lot, but it is not uncommon to have multiple foreign keys on a single table.  There are typically reference tables, for instance, that would have no foreign key relationships (or perhaps a relationship if you keep track of who is inserting rows into the table).

Comment: I want to have those fields but I want to avoid the cost. Is it okay if I removed the FK and just let them be without the `CHECK` constraint if I know I will never insert a wrong value in them?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 . . . .I recommend that you define the data model *correctly*.  If you find that performance is an issue, then address performance.  The checks on the existence of values are unlikely to be the performance gain that you need -- existing indexes on tables, for instance, are much more expensive than checking the foreign key values.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix up foreign keys and checks - there are two different constraint types. For example check accepts nulls and foreign keys not (exception: on delete set null fk option).

When rows are inserted/updated in database set od step is beeing executed, e.g. checking existance of tables, columns, veryfing privileges. Where you have fk database engine must verify contraint before inserting/updateing data to the table - it's additional step to execute.

I have never expirienced situation, when fk painfully slowed down the database operations duration.

Comment: Thank you. But I want to have a foreign key that can accept nulls. Should I not take that as a foreign key then?

Comment: Generaly, it's not a good idea to omit fk. I don't know SQL Server specifications, but in Oracle fk accepts nulls. Could you verify this hipotesis?